# C++: одновременная обработка нескольких TCP-соединений

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сокет

Установлено 32 TCP-соединения. Нужно одновременно со всех 32 соединений считывать приходящие данные. Я думаю реализовать это на создании потоков. Как это сделать? Нужно что-то наподобие пула потоков.

Comment: Изучайте "Асинхронность", типичный пример: boost::asio...

Answer (score 2):

Можно конечно сделать 32 потока, и в каждом обрабатывать данные. А можно использовать [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)/poll/epoll/kpoll/[IOCP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports).

Можно ли это сделать на потоках? можно конечно. Работа с сокетом из потока ничем не отличается от работы с сокетом из главного потока. Главное, аккуратно его туда передать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь.